# Fatal Error:Call to a member function num_rows() on a non-object

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

As I have done codeigniter project, transferred the files from local server to live server, Here everything seems correct,

http://royal.skylabsinc.in/

Yet shows an error..Pls help me out in this...
here an screen shot

> " Fatal error: Call to a member function num_rows() on a non-object in
>   /home2/skylabsi/public_html/royal/system/libraries/Session.php on line
>   215 "

Comment: You need to provide more context to your question, the code section that is giving the error, what have you tried, etc.

Comment: application >config > autoload.php following code here $autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session');   we are calling inbuilt "CI_Session" class in the above name "session"

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I just had a similar issue and this may be useful for someone. For me, the problem was that the sessions table in the mysql database was corrupted and needed to be repaired.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error. You can try to create **ci_session** table in your database. It has resolved my problem.

Comment: This was a great pointer for me, when you migrate from one server to another, a wrong database credentials can also result in this error.

Answer (score 1):

`/home2/skylabsi/public_html/royal/system/libraries/Session.php` suggests that the problem has to do with the session.

`Call to a member function num_rows() on a non-object` suggests that an expected object is null, most likely caused by a bad query from the database.

I also was able to load the page when I first clicked the link, but refreshing/revisiting fails. Checked on a different browser to start a fresh session, got the same thing. First load is fine, subsequent ones aren't. This again suggests an issue with the session.

Comment: Session works perfect in local server but when put to live server ..this shows an error..

Comment: I can't give any more of an answer without more context. What is the code, what have you done, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess, your localserver is windows and live server is linux. If so then most probably you have named your modal with different capitalization in the file name, class name & calling name.

Class names must have the first letter capitalized with the rest of the name lowercase. Make sure your class extends the base Model class.

The file name will be a lower case version of your class name.

Comment: Your guess is right, windows to linux... We have used inbuilt sessions of codeigniter, we are calling the session by the name "session" in autoload config file..      In system library class name is "CI_Session" this stored in file name "Session.php"

Answer (score 0):

add the following code to the class

```
private $CI;

public function __construct()
{
     $this->CI = &get_instance();
     $this->load->library('session');
     $this->load->database();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Very quick and short answer is:

Make sure you have '**`CI_SESSION`**' table on your server database if you set **`$this->load->library('session');`**  in your **`config/autoload.php`**.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ci_sessions` (
  `session_id` varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ip_address` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_agent` varchar(120) NOT NULL,
  `last_activity` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_data` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`session_id`),
  KEY `last_activity_idx` (`last_activity`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

if you using **`CI_SESSION`** then must you have **`CI_SESSION`** table.

Answer (score 0):

I too faced this error though CI_SESSIONS table exists in database.
The solution is :

As on my live server i had created database user and database but i didn't assigned User to the Database and hence it was an  permission issue and the mysql user through which i was connecting didn't had permission to read DB and hence the table CI_SESSIONS.

Answer (score 0):

This one working for me

> Remove this two line form your config.php

```
$config['sess_use_database']     = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']       = 'ci_sessions';
```